# Understanding why apt-get will remove certain packages

Tags: ubuntu, debian, package-management, apt

Is there any easy way to figure out why apt-get will remove certain packages when doing `apt-get remove` on others?

I'm removing just a bunch of font files, and all of sudden `apt-get` thinks that my `mate-desktop-environment-core`, `ubuntu-mate-default-settings` need to be removed as well. Because there are many font files to remove, it is really impractical to try them out one by one to see which one is causing the triggered removal. Is there any easy way to do that?

Here are the details:

First, what's being removed are just a bunch of font files:

```
$ cat | xargs
fonts-beng-extra
fonts-deva-extra
fonts-gargi
fonts-gubbi
fonts-gujr-extra
fonts-liberation
fonts-liberation2
fonts-nakula
fonts-navilu
fonts-orya-extra
fonts-pagul
fonts-sahadeva
fonts-samyak-deva
fonts-samyak-gujr
fonts-samyak-mlym
fonts-samyak-taml
fonts-sarai
fonts-telu-extra
fonts-ubuntu
ttf-ubuntu-font-family
fonts-beng-extra fonts-deva-extra fonts-gargi fonts-gubbi fonts-gujr-extra fonts-liberation fonts-liberation2 fonts-nakula fonts-navilu fonts-orya-extra fonts-pagul fonts-sahadeva fonts-samyak-deva fonts-samyak-gujr fonts-samyak-mlym fonts-samyak-taml fonts-sarai fonts-telu-extra fonts-ubuntu ttf-ubuntu-font-family
```

Now remove them:

```
% apt-get remove fonts-beng-extra fonts-deva-extra fonts-gargi fonts-gubbi fonts-gujr-extra fonts-liberation fonts-liberation2 fonts-nakula fonts-navilu fonts-orya-extra fonts-pagul fonts-sahadeva fonts-samyak-deva fonts-samyak-gujr fonts-samyak-mlym fonts-samyak-taml fonts-sarai fonts-telu-extra fonts-ubuntu ttf-ubuntu-font-family
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  fonts-beng-extra fonts-deva-extra fonts-gargi fonts-gubbi fonts-gujr-extra
  fonts-liberation fonts-liberation2 fonts-nakula fonts-navilu fonts-orya-extra
  fonts-pagul fonts-sahadeva fonts-samyak-deva fonts-samyak-gujr
  fonts-samyak-mlym fonts-samyak-taml fonts-sarai fonts-telu-extra fonts-ubuntu
  mate-desktop-environment-core mate-session-manager plymouth-label
  plymouth-theme-ubuntu-mate-logo ttf-ubuntu-font-family
  ubuntu-mate-default-settings
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 25 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I.e., my `mate-desktop-environment-core`, `ubuntu-mate-default-settings` etc are among the list to be removed. How come? Thx.

```
$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Answer (score 4):

Ahh~, as usual:

```
$ apt-cache depends mate-desktop-environment-core | grep font 
 |Depends: fonts-cantarell
  Depends: fonts-ubuntu
```

(I was doing the checking in previous version instead of the needed v18.04) In 17.04 at least:

```
$ apt-cache depends mate-desktop-environment-core | grep font || echo not found
not found
```